# Как запустить Java Web Start приложение по клику на обычную кнопку?

Tags: javaws, javascript, java

Хочу запустить javaws приложение без "специальной" кнопки со словом "Launch", а просто по клику, например, на обычную кнопку? Со "специальной" кнопкой я разобрался:

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var url = "someJnlpFile.jnlp";
    deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<button onclick=deployJava.launch("someJnlpFile.jnlp")>
    Click Me!
</button>
```