# Как добавить кнопку запуска Java Web Start в GWT-приложение

Tags: javaws, gwt, java

Как добавить кнопку запуска javaws приложения в gwt-приложение, если на чистом javascript это должно выглядеть [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, будет достаточно воспользоваться [JSNI](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) для написания обработчика. А элемент

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
```

можно добавить, например, в root вот так:

```
ScriptElement e = Document.get().createScriptElement(); 
e.setSrc("http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"); 
DOM.appendChild(RootPanel.get().getElement(), e.<Element>cast());
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь можно даже не пользоваться JSNI. Достаточно добавить экземпляр класса HTML:

```
HTML html = new HTML("<label onclick=deployJava.launch(\"test.jnlp\")>Label text</label>");
RootPanel.get().add(html);
```